# crud update doesnt work properly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

so i make a crud using netcore
i update the data but it goes to the bottom of the view
is it possible to make updated data to stay on the place?
i already try using .orderby(id) it doesnt work the updated data still goes to the bottom of the table

Before I update the data:

[image]

After I update the data:

[image]

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var mhsw = _context.Mahasiswas.ToList();
    mhsw.OrderByDescending(m => m.Id);
    return View(mhsw);
}
.....
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(Mahasiswa model)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid) return View(model);
    _context.Mahasiswas.Update(model);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Please don't give off-site links to your code, include the relevant parts in your question.

Comment: What library / controls are you using?

Comment: my bad thx for fixing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call OrderByDescending you get back an ordered sequence according to your condition. The source sequence is not changed by the call.
You need to assign the ordered sequence to the variable that you want to show

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var mhsw = _context.Mahasiswas.OrderByDescending(m => m.Id).ToList();
    return View(mhsw);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var mhsw = _context.Mahasiswas.ToList();
            mhsw=mhsw.OrderByDescending(m => m.Id).ToList();<-----------------
            return View(mhsw);
        }
```

This will work.

Comment: my bad your answer were actually right
im really sorry
but Appreciate for the help